# Get value from links with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a div box with some images that the user can click. When the user clicks the image i want a ajax call that will provide me with the product images from that provider.

Like this:

```
<div id="phones" style="display:none;">
    <a href="#" value=1 id=HTC class=vendorLinks>
        <img src=/images/vendors/htc.png>
    </a>
    <a href="#" value=2 id=Nokia class=vendorLinks>
         <img src=/images/vendors/nokia.png>
    </a>
    <a href="#" value=3 id=SonyEricsson class=vendorLinks>IMAGE</a>
    <a href="#" value=4 id=Samsung class=vendorLinks>IMAGE</a>
    <a href="#" value=5 id=BlackBerry class=vendorLinks>IMAGE</a>
    <a href="#" value=6 id=Sonim class=vendorLinks>IMAGE</a>
    <a href="#" value=8 id=Motorola class=vendorLinks>IMAGE</a>     
</div>
```

When i click on one of the links i want a ajax call against the url /mob/changePhone

```
$('#cPhone').click(function(){
        $('#phones').fadeIn('slow');

        });
        $('.vendorLinks').click(function(){


    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",

    url: "/mob/changePhone/<?=$userID?>",

    data: data,
    success: function()
    {

        $('.vendorLinks').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#phone').fadeIn('slow').html(this);

    }
});
});
```

The php function looks like this:

```
function changePhone($UID = null)
            {

                $UID        = $this->uri->segment(3);
                $vendor = // How can i get the value from the link?
                echo $vendor;
                echo "<br>";
                echo $UID;  
                if(!$UID)
                    {
                        echo "Error: No user ID given!";
                    } 
                if($vendor)
                    {
                        // Do something
                    }
                // get the vendor logo.
                $vendors = $this->getVendors();
                $string = "";
                foreach($vendors as $maker){
                    $string .= "<a href=\"#\" value=". $maker['id'] . " id=". $this->spaceRemover($maker['name']) ." class=vendorLinks><img width=100px height=100px style=border:0; padding-left: 5px; src=". $maker['imgPath'] . "></a>";
                }
                return $string;
            }
```

How can i get the value from the link?

Hopes anyone know how i can do this and maybe tell me if this peace of code is bad.
Its for internal use so security is not a priority :-).

Thanks.

Best Regards
Audunfr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the data variable in your ajax call.
Like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/mob/changePhone/<?=$userID?>",
        data: {vendor : $(this).attr('id')},
        success: function()
        {

                $('.vendorLinks').fadeOut('slow');
                $('#phone').fadeIn('slow').html(this);

        }
});
```

Then you can access the vendor's name by the php-variable `$_POST['vendor']`.

Comment: Thanks Morningcoffee. This worked like a charm. Thank you so much.